# Mutation algorithm efficiency

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, genetic-algorithm

Instead of iterating through each element in a matrix and checking if random() returns lower than the rate of mutation, does it work if you generate a certain amount of random indices that match the rate of mutation or is there some other method?

Comment: If possible, can you please provide some sample data to illustrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: Maybe this is jargon that I'm not understanding, but I think it's unclear what you mean by "rate of mutation."  How does that correlate to matrices / matrix elements?

Comment: If you are working in `numpy`, there is almost always a better way that iterating through an array using a Python-level for-loop. Without more details though, this question is too broad

Comment: More anecdotal evidence that the question might be not entirely clear: *I personally* have no idea what you are talking about, despite the fact that every single tag seems rather familiar. Please provide an [mcve] and explain clearly what isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Suppose your gene length is 100 and your mutation rate is 0.1, then picking 100*0.1=10 random indices and mutating them is faster than generating & checking 100 numbers.